# Comparing dictionaries containing actually equatable types, based on non-equatable data structures

Tags: swift, generics, dictionary, comparison, equality

So I want to equate two dictionaries of the same type `[AnyLanguage: SortedList<String>]`.
`AnyLanguage` conforms to `Hashable`, and therefore also `Equatable`, so it's not a problem. `SortedList` on the other hand does not conform to `Equatable`, as it is generic over `Element`, which has no restrictions:

```
public struct SortedList<Element> { ... }
```

Now, I have implemented the equality operator for `SortedList`, when its `Elements` conform to `Equatable`:

```
public func ==<T: Equatable>(left: SortedList<T>, right: SortedList<T>) -> Bool
```

---

Now, when comparing two of the aforementioned dictionaries:

```
let dictA: [AnyLanguage: SortedList<String>] = [:]
let dictB: [AnyLanguage: SortedList<String>] = [:]

dictA == dictB
```

I get the following error:

[image: Error]

I assume that the compiler is complaining because `SortedList` does not conform to `Equatable`, even though I have implemented the comparison operator for equatable `Element`s (which `SortedList<String>` would be able to use, as `String` is equatable).

How can I compare the two dictionaries?

Comment: This is the same problem as in https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7172: "Why can't I make Array<T: Equatable> conform to Equatable?". – You cannot make `SortedList<Element>` conform to Equatable *only if* `Element` is Equatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `==` operator for dictionaries requires that both Key and Value
type conform to `Equatable`.

You have implemented a (restricted) `==` operator for `SortedList<Element>`.
But implementing a `==` operator for a type does not make that type
`Equatable` automatically. The conformance must be declared explicitly.

Unfortunately, it is (currently) not possible to make `SortedList<Element>` conform to `Equatable` *only if* `Element`
is `Equatable`. The same problem exists for arrays, compare
[Why can't I make Array conform to Equatable?](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7172) for a discussion
in the Apple developer forum.

The only solutions – as far as I know – are to make `SortedList<Element>`
conform to  `Equatable` unconditionally (as in [Cristik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34704696/1187415)), or to define
a custom comparison operator for dictionaries

```
func ==<Key : Equatable, T : Equatable>(lhs: [Key : SortedList<T>], rhs: [Key : SortedList<T>]) -> Bool {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SortedList` is not `Equatable`, so `Dictionary` can't compare the elements. You need to declare as `Equatable`, and implement `==` without the generic constraint. This will work:

```
public struct SortedList<Element>: Equatable { ... }

public func ==<T>(left: SortedList<T>, right: SortedList<T>) -> Bool
```

If you want to restrict your `SortedList` to `Equatable` elements, you can declare it to accept only stuff that conforms to `Equatable`

```
public struct SortedList<Element: Equatable>: Equatable
```

however for your `SortedList` I think `Comparable` would suit better.

Comment: `SortedList` can't simply be made `Equatable`,as I can't compare the elements, if `Element` is not `Equatable`. That'S the whole problem.

Comment: @MarcusRossel that can also be done by adding a type constraint to `Element`, I updated my answer with this.